# Settimeout is not working properly and taking the first value

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, settimeout, loading

I am trying to use setinterval to change the value of secondCall.
But after 2 secs the value of loading may change to false, but the settimeout is taking the first value that is true.
How can I make the settimeout take the updated value of loading?

```
export const sleep = async (callback = null, timeInMs = 3000) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(callback), timeInMs));

useEffect(() => {
  async function delay() {
    await sleep(30000);
    if (loading) {
      setSecondCall(true);
    }
  }
  delay();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

Like after 30 seconds if the loading is equal to false it shouldn't do the changes on secondCall.

Comment: If you call `sleep(30000)` then that value will be stored in `callback` because your sleep function looks like this `sleep(callback, time)`. If you don't need that `callback` variable you can just remove it.  Also I wonder why you use `if (loading)` ? Where is the `loading` variable coming from? And what is `setSecondCall(true)`?

Comment: loading is just a state, at first it's set to true, because the data is still loading, if the data gets loaded, the value of loading will turn to false, but if the data doesn't load within 30 seconds, i should run the set setSecondCall(true) to change the state of secondCall which will trigger a useeffect afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

`loading` in your `delay` function is closure-captured, it will not be changed with time but you can achieve what you want with `useRef`.

```
export default function App() {
  const loadingRef = useRef(true); // same as loading
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [secondCall, setSecondCall] = useState(false);

  // hook to update loadingRef only
  useEffect(() => {
    loadingRef.current = loading;
  }, [loading]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function delay() {
      // btw, in your sleep the delay is 2nd parameter
      await sleep(null, 30000);
      // loadingRef is closure-captured
      // but .current is not and will be reflected as expected
      if (loadingRef.current === true) {
        setSecondCall(true);
      }
    }
    delay();
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">...</div>;
}
```